# Redmine error when editing a task from iOS (delete issue description)

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins, redmine-api

Editing a task from a mobile phone on iOS removes the entire description of the task. Tested on two devices. With the same actions on an Android phone, everything works correctly. Tell me what could be the problem.
Redmine Version:
`

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                4.1.5.stable
  Ruby version                   2.6.9-p207 (2021-11-24) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  5.2.6
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
  Mailer queue                   ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::AsyncAdapter
  Mailer delivery                smtp
SCM:
  Subversion                     1.14.1
  Mercurial                      5.6.1
  Bazaar                         3.1.0
  Git                            2.30.2
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  redmine_agile                  1.6.2
  redmine_checklists             3.1.20
  redmine_resources              1.0.6
  redmine_wysiwyg_editor         0.23.0
  redmineup_tags                 2.0.11
  time_logger                    0.5.4
```

`
Thanks in advance.

Tested on 2 different iOS and Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been addressed in the latest versions of the Wysiwyg plugin.
You should update your plugins and try again.

More details here: https://github.com/taqueci/redmine_wysiwyg_editor/issues/141

Comment: Thank you so much. Updated the plugin to version 0.27.0 The update solved my problem.